# No creating database in Hostinger VPS

Tags: database, vps

I go to the control panel i.e. court http://100.100.100.100:8080 log in then datastores go in click add new datastores write datastores name (sump) in description write (none) directory (/home/root/database) click (save change) and gets out (Unable to add new datastore.
Unable to write to provided datastore directory. Check that the user AMP is running as has full read/write/execute access to that directory.) how to create in the end?